# BerkeleyDB: Receiving truncated keys to bt_compare function in python BTREE

Tags: python, berkeley-db, bsddb

I am using [BerkeleyDB 6.0](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/server/db.html) with [bsddb3](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm) python drivers. I have a dataset with `BTREE` access method having keys as strings representing floating point numbers. I have set a compare function to be used in `set_bt_compare()`.

When I try to use `db.set_range(key)` function, the keys that the compare function receives are sometimes truncated. for instance,

```
--------------------------------------------------
'left :1378934633890000.0'
--------------------------------------------------
'right:13789346362'
```

Here, the right key should be `'1378934636286548.8'`.

Has anyone seen this problem? have any suggestions as to how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was my fault. I hadn't set the `bt_compare` method when adding the data. I did that and now there's no truncated data. Just in case anyone else having the same problem, make sure you correctly set the comparison method each time you read/write data.